# Filter one user's data in a table using php and mysql but user belongs to two tables in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php. I am developing a web application.

I have two separate tables in data base as users and bmi.

I use session for user login.

In users' tables there are 6 columns as id, firstname, lastname, username, email and password.

In bmi table there are 5 columns as id, username, bmi_value, category and date.

In my web application users can calculate their bmi values. when an user calculate their bmi, the data store in bmi table. if another user log and calculate bmi, his data store in next row in bmi table.

If the first user calculate his bmi again, the value store in the next row and id column value shows as 3. like wise it happens.

What I need is, i want to filter one particular user's all data in bmi table and display when he click the bmi_history button of the BMI page of the system.

Should i link bmi and users table or are there any way?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Yes. This is a JOIN.

Comment: I am sorry. But id of user different in two tables. as a example if user A is no.3 of users table but in bmi table he got different and several ids when he count bmi several times. is it ok?

Comment: No. The user id should be consistent across tables. You should store the user id, not the username, in bmi.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're trying to solve is a common one. Within the world of databases, this relationship is called [primary key and foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp). Each row in the user table is given a unique id. Each row in the bmi table has an id column and a user_id column. The bmi.id column will be unique for each row. But the bmi.user_id will refer to an existing user.id value.

Within the world of MVCs, the user model and the bmi model share a "one to many" relationship. Each user can have many bmi data points.